# How do I read line 3 from the console output in Ruby?

Tags: android, ruby

I want to read each line at the console and then split them by `" "`.

The output at the console is:

```
List of devices attached
0125Mt3B19ct7343    device
07v6584d0a8a6cy7    device
```

I want to get the Device Ids in an array since I am attaching multiple Android devices to a USB hub.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
class Init

  $devices = Array.new

  def getDevice

    cmd = "adb devices"
    value = `#{cmd}`
    $deviceCount =  value.lines.count
    puts "#$deviceCount Devices are Connected to the USB Hub"
    puts $deviceCount
..........

  end
```

The above code is useless as I am unable to get the correct count of the devices connected. I am using `lines` since I cannot figure out what else I could use.

I want to read the output at the terminal and skip the first line that is " List of devices attached" and then split the following lines which have the Device ids so that I can insert them into an array containing just the device ids.

For instance:

```
devices[] = {0125Mt3B19ct7343, 07v6584d0a8a6cy7, ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an untested version of your code, written a bit more idiomatically:

```
class Devices

  @@devices = []

  def self.get_devices
    @@devices = `adb devices`.split("\n")[1 .. -1]
    device_count = @@devices.size
    puts "#{ device_count } Devices are Connected to the USB Hub"
    puts device_count
  end
end

devices = Devices::get_devices
```

Things to pay attention to:

- Don't name a class "Init". A class should be a thing, not an action. I took a liberty and named it "Devices", which really isn't correct, because a class should be a *single* thing, but in this case you're looking for a list of devices. `DeviceList` might be a better name.
- `$devices`... um... is totally wrong. Don't use a global until you understand what globals are for. Instead, use a class variable, such as `@@devices` in the case of a class called `Devices`.
- `Array.new` is oh-so-pretty, but accomplishes nothing that `[]` doesn't do for this purpose, so use the shorter, and more concise `[]`.
- `def getDevice` - don't use camelCase for Ruby methods. By convention methods and variables are snake_case, and Classes and Modules are camelCase. Follow the convention if you intend to ever publish your code or get a job programming Ruby or Rails.
- `split("\n")[1 .. -1]` splits the output received from `` `adb devices` `` into separate lines and returns the second to the last lines. That means you get instant removal of the "List of devices attached" line returned.

Devising these sort of interfaces is always a learning experience. You probably want to be able to get the current list of devices at the last poll, plus have another method that gets the current devices now and update the variable for the last-seen devices:

```
class DeviceList

  @@devices = []

  def self.get_devices
    @@devices = `adb devices`.split("\n")[1 .. -1]
  end

  def self.device_list
    get_devices() if @@devices.empty?
    @@devices
  end

end

devices = DeviceList::get_device_list

device_count = devices.size
puts "#{ device_count } Devices are Connected to the USB Hub"
puts device_count
```

This lets you request the current list using `Devices::device_list` or force a new (re)load of the list using `Devices::get_devices`. Note also, that this removes the output and counting of the size of the returned list from the class. Those actions can occur in a class, but for this sort of code I'd probably rely on Ruby's ability to print list, and make the class only return the list of devices. YMMV.

There are a lot of smarter people here on Stack Overflow, who can help you with the proper taxonomy for defining names for methods and such.

Comment: Thanks Sir !! I appreciate your Help. This worked really well. I just need to add a few more things and i ll be good. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks For the Notes. I shall be paying attention to the pointers. I appreciate it.